# React-Table :Custom-pagination design

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-table

I create custom pagination in my react-table, I add the page number which you can see in below description now I want to add the forward-slash after each page number  I tried something but its look like very different from my needs..so  give the appropriate way to do that 
thanks for helping in advance

code which I tried is shown below

```
[![import React from "react";
import './Pagination.css'

type IProps = {
    pages: number,
    page: number,
    PageButtonComponent: any,
    onPageChange: any,
    previousText: string,
    nextText: string,
    onPageSizeChange: any;
    pageSizeOptions: any;
    data: any;
    showPageSizeOptions:any;
    rowsText:string;
    pageSize:number
}

type IState = {
    visiblePages: any
}

const defaultButton = (props: any) => <button {...props}>{props.children}</button>;

export default class Pagination extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);

        this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            visiblePages: this.getVisiblePages(0, props.pages)
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Readonly<IProps>): void {

        if (this.props.pages !== nextProps.pages) {
            this.setState({
                visiblePages: this.getVisiblePages(0, nextProps.pages)
            });
        }

        this.changePage(nextProps.page + 1);
    }

    filterPages = (visiblePages: any, totalPages: number) => {

        return visiblePages.filter((page: number) => page <= totalPages);
    };

    getVisiblePages = (page: number, total: number) => {

        if (total < 7) {
            return this.filterPages(\[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\], total);
        } else {
            if (page % 5 >= 0 && page > 4 && page + 2 < total) {
                return \[1, page - 1, page, page + 1, total\];
            } else if (page % 5 >= 0 && page > 4 && page + 2 >= total) {
                return \[1, total - 3, total - 2, total - 1, total\];
            } else {
                return \[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, total\];
            }
        }
    };

    changePage(page: any) {

        const activePage = this.props.page + 1;

        if (page === activePage) {
            return;
        }

        const visiblePages = this.getVisiblePages(page, this.props.pages);

        this.setState({
            visiblePages: this.filterPages(visiblePages, this.props.pages)
        });
        this.props.onPageChange(page - 1);

    }

    render() {

        const { PageButtonComponent = defaultButton } = this.props;
        const { visiblePages } = this.state;
        const activePage = this.props.page + 1;

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className='col-md-4 leftpagination'>
                    <span className={"totalText"}>{"Total  " + this.props.data.length}</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    {this.props.showPageSizeOptions &&
                        <span className="select-wrap -pageSizeOptions">
                            <select
                                onChange={e => this.props.onPageSizeChange(Number(e.target.value))}
                                value={this.props.pageSize}
                            >
                                {this.props.pageSizeOptions.map((option:number, i:number) => (
                                    <option key={i} value={option}>
                                        {option} {this.props.rowsText}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </span>}
                </div>
                <div className='col-md-8'>
                    <div className="Table__pagination">
                        <div className="Table__prevPageWrapper">
                            <PageButtonComponent
                                className="Table__pageButton"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    if (activePage === 1) return;
                                    this.changePage(activePage - 1);
                                }}
                                disabled={activePage === 1}
                            >
                                {this.props.previousText}
                            </PageButtonComponent>
                        </div>
                        <div className="Table__visiblePagesWrapper">
                            {visiblePages.map((page: number, index: number, array: \[\]) => {
                                return (
                                    <PageButtonComponent
                                        key={page}
                                        className={
                                            activePage === page
                                                ? "Table__pageButton Table__pageButton--active"
                                                : "Table__pageButton"
                                        }
                                        onClick={this.changePage.bind(null, page)}
                                    >
                                        {array\[index - 1\] + 2 < page ? `...${page}` : + page}
                                    </PageButtonComponent>
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <div className="Table__nextPageWrapper">
                            <PageButtonComponent
                                className="Table__pageButton"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    if (activePage === this.props.pages) return;
                                    this.changePage(activePage + 1);
                                }}
                                disabled={activePage === this.props.pages}
                            >
                                {this.props.nextText}
                            </PageButtonComponent>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        );
    }
}][1]][1]
```

I want the result like the page looks like   <  1  /  2  /  3.../  11  >
but when I tried its look like < /1 /2 /3 ...>

[image: what i want]

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written simple code for pagination design. You can use it.
**HTML for pagination**

```
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
```

**Style for pagination link**

```
<style>
  a::after {
    content: " /";
    margin: 0 5px;
  }

  a:last-child::after {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Your pagination link will be look like below
[image]

You can modified the design as per your site.
Hope this will work for you!

Comment: your solution is appreciated but see my code it's not possible to put <a> tag similar like you mentioned in the answer, this one I also know but I want to fit this solution in my code this is the main problem